# How to further analyze suspicious traffic

Tags: network, forensics, wireshark

I've been monitoring my network traffic with Little Snitch, and today, when launching Chrome, just the default Chrome tab (shows most frequent sites), it alerted me Chrome was trying to connect over SSL to the domain

```
goldenticket.disconnect.me
```

According to whois lookup, this domain is registered to a "dedicated server" that is also an Amazon AWS instance (goldenticket-658146952.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com). The entry indicates its IP address is in Ashburn, VA, right outside of D.C.

Pointing a browser at disconnect.me brings up some company site about browsing security, with a product called *Disconnect* that I have never heard of or installed on my machine.

What else can I determine about this traffic? I can't account for it, and I've run Chrome several sessions with LS3 without seeing this before.

Comment: It looks like its a browser plugin.  Did it somehow get installed/enabled on Chrome?  I suppose you could always Fiddler the connection if you wanted to see what was going on underneath the SSL.  I doubt you'd see much, but you'd see any requests that are made.

Comment: I don't understand how Fiddler works. How can it decrypt SSL traffic?

Comment: Oh and @raz -- no, this was not installed in Chrome, unless that's somehow hidden from me.

Comment: So Fiddler is an HTTP proxy that can also act as an SSL proxy.  You trust their certificate and they act as a MitM for your connection.  This will make any SSL connection you create completely insecure until you remove the certificate from your trusted store.  It allows application designers to test their code underneath the SSL, or just for people to test out what is actually being passed to server's during authentication.  http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: I guess here's not the place, but I'm still unclear how this is *possible*. Fiddler is tricking the application into using it's cert, basically? Why would it not then use the correct cert to make the actual connection, so as to not make things insecure when testing?

Comment: It's not tricking anything.  You download the client.  You install their certificate into your trusted store.  It's called something like _DO_NOT_TRUST_Fiddler.  You have to do some configuring, but then your HTTP/HTTPS connections will go through Fiddler's server's.  They do a legit secure connection with your target and then send it back to you.  You'll have the private key for their certificate, so through configuration you can have the client (which is collecting traffic) decrypt the sessions for you.

Comment: Installing Fiddler: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/installfiddler  Configuring Fiddler: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurefiddler  HTTPS decryption Setup: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/DecryptHTTPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:[goldenticket.disconnect.me](http://support.getadblock.com/discussions/questions/501-what-is-the-deal-with-disconnect)

You probably have adblock add-on installed in your chrome brower

Comment: That's very not nefarious. Thx.